# Show products on homepage breaks page 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, products, home

I am currently found this solution to post products on homepage

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="7"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

once i paste above code inside CMS > Pages > homepage page underneath the text and save it replaces page completely with procuts page.

1. Is there way to just add product on bottom of home page while still keeping homepage text that i entered in CMS page?
2. Somehow it only shows one product even though i have 40 in the category 7

Comment: I tried that created custom **list_home.phtml** page inside my custom theme and added code from that answer to it and it did not even show products at all when i pointed to that template in above code **{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="7"  template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}**

Comment: Ok you right when i enabled error reporting i saw that same error **Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object** will try to read that answer more carefully

Comment: Must admit that that answer in the link provided is super unclear they need to edit it a bit otherwise its super confusing as of what to replace where and how

Answer (score 3):

For those confused with answer from the link you need to use following code in CMS page

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="10" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}
```

then copy file **list.phtml** in

```
/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml 
/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list_home.phtml
```

and edit **list_home.phtml** Just wrap code block found on lines line 73. 133 and 178 with similar if statements.

```
<?php
    $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
?>
    <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

becomes

```
<? 
$_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after');
if ($_nameAfterChildren): ?>

<?php
    $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
        echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

and similar solution for the other two blocks.