# Product list by category in CMS page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, cms, product-list, ce-1.9.2.0

I have 5 stores, each store with 3 categories.

Every store has it's own CMS page. I want to show the products of a given category of those 3 categories in store's CMS page (e.g. categories 12, 13, 27, or just category 12).

I tried all of these :

- http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-display-products-from-the-category-on-the-home-page.html#gref
- [Show products on homepage breaks page 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35194/show-products-on-homepage-breaks-page-1-9)
- [Show Specific Categories On Magento Home Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43246/show-specific-categories-on-magento-home-page)

Unfortunately, unsuccessfully...

Result is absolutely nothing... Inspecting the page, I get blank divs where the code were supposed to appear.

Products are in stock and available, yet they appear in "new_products" widget.

I've followed every single question and tuto about this, and it simply doesn't work...

Points of interest:

- My Magento version is 1.9.2.
- The block code that I'm using right now is this:
  {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="12" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
- I've cleaned magento's cache hundreds of times

If you need further information, please let me know. I'll be waiting hopefully for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Magento 1.9.2.x, You need to create permission for 'catalog/product_list' block from '**System->Permissions->Blocks**'

Comment: Hey @Sohel, thank you! I've just added "module/product_list" to my permissions, also unsuccesful. In my CMS content editor, I'm using this:
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="12" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
Am I missing something?

Comment: Blocks permissions was added in Magento 1.9.2.2

Comment: Updated my answer. @CarlosEduardoSantos

Comment: @SohelRana 's answer works! Finally! It's showing all categories instead of selected one, but at least it's showing something. Thank you, sir!