# How do I display products on home page from a category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, rwd

I use the following widget to display products on the home page for new products

```
<p>{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="10" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}</p>
```

How do I list products from a category under this?

I have tried using this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

but it doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 1.9 adds some permissions feature about including blocks in CMS content

Check this
[Product list by category in CMS page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94026/product-list-by-category-in-cms-page?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Have you create permission. If not then you can create permission from **System->Permissions->Blocks**