# Display Promotion Products in HomePage

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions, home

Is there a way to display a product has the price changed using `Promotions > Catalog Price Rules` on HomePage?

I did a Promotion for a Client Group and I need to show this products as 'featured' or something like this.

I tried using a block: `{{block type="filterproducts/newproduct_home_list" product_count="8" column_count="5" template="filterproducts/grid.phtml"}}` but didn't had any success.

Thanks

Comment: The quick way in my opinion is to apply the rules in category with name sale or whatever you want and view that category with a nice banner per product to show its discount %. Anything further this approach is possible, you should rewrite or extend the catalog rule model get the collection build an index controller etc etc. This would be very resource hungry for your installation and needs time to build and maintain that is going to be a waste when it's so simple to build that sale category.

Comment: With 'no success' what do you mean? What was the outcome? You did set the block 'filterproducts/newproduct_home_list' as allowed to display? Ref: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94026/product-list-by-category-in-cms-page

Answer (score 1):

Not having any of your code available, it is not entirely clear why your cms block is not working.

As per my comments on your question, it is very likely that you need to set the block as allowed to display.

Refer here:

[Product list by category in CMS page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94026/product-list-by-category-in-cms-page)

However, consider to not use a custom block and filters to display what you need. Use a category.

Assign all the noted products to a new category. Then use the core blocks to display that in your page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="12" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

No need to go create any new code/modules and you can set a different template to handle the display of this list (if needed to display different to your usual product category lists)

You may also be interested in this: http://www.proxiblue.com.au/blog/smarter-cms-category-product-limits/

You can also automate the category by using a tool such as this - http://www.proxiblue.com.au/premium-modules/magento-dynamic-category-products.html (yes some blatant self promotion)

simply set the rules, and forget about it. Your sales category will stay updated automatically, daily. No need to manually manage your category products going forward.